# Hessian of a black box function that uses Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, numerical-methods, differentiation, automatic-differentiation

First of all I am very new to Python and machine learning, so please excuse my ignorance on what might be a very basic issue; I do appreciate any input on this question!

I have a very complicated scalar-valued multivariable function implemented in Python that uses Pytorch functionalities (it is actually a composition of a neural network and operations that depend on outputs from the network), and I wish to find the gradient vector and Hessian matrix of this function at certain points. Besides `numdifftools` which does finite difference and is not very fast and accurate when the dimension of input is high, are there alternatives? Something that seems promising is the the `torch.autograd` which I believe is used to compute the gradient of neural networks, however, can it compute the gradient and Hessian of any black-box function that runs Pytorch code? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: In general yes, but I have never tried to do that so I can't provide much detail. Perhaps [this](http://www.philipzucker.com/pytorch-trajectory-optimization-3-plugging-hessian/)  will be helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch most efficient Jacobian/Hessian calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480578/pytorch-most-efficient-jacobian-hessian-calculation)