# Getting the output's grad with respect to the input

Tags: python, pytorch, ode, autograd

I'm currently trying to implement an ODE Solver with Pytorch, my solution requires computing the gradient of each output wtr to its input.

```
y = model(x)

for i in range(len(y)): #compute output grad wrt input
       y[i].backward(retain_graph=True)
    
ydx=x.grad
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to compute the gradients for each output in the batch, since the code gets messy for higher order ODEs and PDEs.
I tried using:

```
torch.autograd.backward(x,y,retain_graph=True)
```

without much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `torch.autograd.functional.jacobian` if your version of PyTorch has the API implemented. I am doing the same for the Burger's equation, and posted this thread on the same subject: [PyTorch how to compute second order jacobian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978232/pytorch-how-to-compute-second-order-jacobian)

Solving PDE with DL is a hot topic right now

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.autograd.grad` function to obtain gradients directly. One problem is that it requires the output (`y`) to be scalar. Since your output is an array, you will still need to loop through its values.

The call will look something like this.

```
[torch.autograd.grad(outputs=out, inputs=x, retain_graph=True)[0][i] 
    for i, out in enumerate(y)]
```

Here is an example of what I mean. Let's consider variable `x` with values `[1,2,3]` and a model that just squares its input.

```
x = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3])
x.requires_grad = True

def model(x): return x ** 2

y = model(x)
```

Now, if you call the `torch.autograd.grad` as I have described, you will get:

```
[torch.autograd.grad(outputs=out, inputs=x, retain_graph=True)[0][i] 
    for i, out in enumerate(y)]

# [tensor(2.), tensor(4.), tensor(6.)]
```

Which is the list of derivatives wrt. to values of `x` - `[ydx0, ydx1, ydx2`]