# Calculate Second Gradient with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch, there are two ways of calculating second gradients. The first method is to use `torch.autograd.grad` function, and the other is to use `backward` function. I use the following examples to illustrate it:

Method 1:

```
x=torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.pow(x, 2)
grad_1 = torch.autograd.grad(y, x, create_graph=True)
print(grad_1[0].item())
grad_2 = torch.autograd.grad(grad_1[0], x)
print(grad_2)
```

The result makes sense for me, and the second gradient of the function is 2.

Method 2:

```
x=torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.pow(x, 2) # y=x**2
y.backward(retain_graph=True)
print(x.grad)

y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

When calculating the first gradient, I use `create_graph=True` to make sure that we can use back prorogation method to calculate the second gradient. However, the result is is 12, which is wrong. I was wondering what's wrong with the second method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch most efficient Jacobian/Hessian calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56480578/pytorch-most-efficient-jacobian-hessian-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grad` method from `torch.autograd` to differentiate your function. So the steps would be:

```
>>> import torch
>>> from torch.autograd import grad

>>> x = torch.tensor([3.0], requires_grad=True)
>>> y = torch.pow(x,2)

>>> z = grad(y, x, create_graph=True)
>>> print(grad(z, x, create_graph=True))
>>> (tensor([2.], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>),)
```

Similarly, you can loop through to make the nth derivative.